# Crash on exit when using Visual Studio 2015 debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, crash

I loaded a solution on VS2015 and when I exit WITH the debugger attached, it crashes after exit and cleanup.
The same solution does not crash on VS2012 , neither without the debugger attached.

The crash seems related with the closure of the standard input and output streams, but think I don't use them (as far as I know; it might be being used on some of the libraries attached like png, jpg, postgres...).

```
// Closes the underlying OS file handle, if and only if nt needs to be closed.
// Returns 0 on success; returns the OS error on failure.
static DWORD close_os_handle_nolock(int const fh) throw()
{
[...]
 if (CloseHandle(reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_get_osfhandle(fh))))
        return 0;
[...]
}
```

the fh is a value over 2 (3,4...) so the debugger throws exception when accessing a NULL pointer from _get_osfhandle.

Why does this cleanup crash? How can I detect if I create streams to close then gracefully? Is it a bug from VS2015? (as in vs2012 doesn't happen, and only crashes when debugger is attached).

The source has been tested on other pc's with vs2015.

**EDIT:**
I found the underlying problem here. For some operations the files are open using CreateFile and I get a HANDLE to the file stream. Also, in order to use the opened file in other operations (for example to parse it using the jpg library) the file is reopened using _open_osfhandle

```
int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)filehandle, _O_RDONLY);
FILE* fp = _fdopen(fd, "rb");
```

then, when the program exits, the cleanup routine calls _close for all the file handles created with _open_osfhandle, but, the handle has been already closed using _close(fd); in MY cleanup routine. Either way, the system tries to reclose the same handle identifier on exit, which throws assertion (now is an assert instead of a crash).

Apart of calling _close, what can I do to tell the O.S. the file is already closed and there is no need to crash it?

If I remove my cleanup routine, the assertion disappears as expected.

Comment: Where is this being called from?  If it's any place but the CRT then it's doing the close wrong: _"...To close a file opened with `_get_osfhandle`, call `_close`. ..."_  see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6.aspx

Comment: It is possible that your program messes up something (buffer overflow, writing to memory where it shouldn't, etc.) and on VS2012 you got away with it but no more on VS2015 because the CRT and it's variable's layout are different.

Comment: I found something, I edit the question

Comment: the call is done on the exit of the program, after my code ended and the O.S. is doing his own cleaning.

Comment: seems like Richard is on the track here. The _close is done, but the O.S. is calling it again with the same integer id.

Comment: hey @RichardCritten, I finally found where the _close was missing and that I had to remove my CloseHandles. (It was the JPEG library wich was using the FILE*...). Would you post it as an answer so I can pick it as solution?